# Pycharm Tensorflow2.2 on Pi 4

Tags: python, tensorflow, raspberry-pi, pycharm

I installed Tensorflow on my Raspberry Pi4 model B by this following this instruction.
https://qengineering.eu/install-tensorflow-2.2.0-on-raspberry-pi-4.html
I choos a way with building wheels with Bazel.It took a long time, but I reached success.
After that I download and run PyCharm community edition and of course it doesn't see installed tensorflow and other libs. It's impossible to install Tensorflow by Pycharm tools.
So, how to make Pycharm use already installed libs?

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify a Python Interpreter in PyCharm? If yes, does it correspond to the one you used to install TensorFlow?

The procedure to specify a Python Interpreter in PyCharm is explained in this link: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html

If you installed TensorFlow on a virtual environment, you'll need to add a Python Interpreter in PyCharm as an "existing environment" and point it to the virtual environment you created. This procedure is also explained in the above link.

Comment: Thank you, Lionel Weicker! Specify right Python was the solution. And link helped too